# Do blocks run on new or original thread?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

If I have the method defined below, does the block ("handler") passed to the method get called on the new thread created by `NSOperationQueue`? Or does it get called on the thread it was on when passed to `methodWithCompletionHandler:`?

```
-(void)methodWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSString *message))handler
{
   // Note: We are currently on thread #1. Calling handler(@"my message") here
   //       will run on thread #1.

    NSBlockOperation* someOp = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock: ^{

   // do some stuff
   }];

   [someOp setCompletionBlock:^{
      // Note: Now someOp is completing, but it's in thread #2. Does calling the handler
      //       as below also run in thread #2 or thread #1?
      handler(@"Some message.");
   }];

   NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
   [queue addOperation:someOp];
}
```

Comment: Blocks by themselves have no relation to threads at all, just like functions.

Comment: Yep, I realize that. But there are more complex interactions involved that make the results non-obvious, to me at least. For example, a block with a strong reference to `self` comes to mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The exact execution context for your completion block is not
>   guaranteed but is typically a secondary thread.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591-RH2-SW36

Answer (score 3):

In the example you have posted, the block in someOp would be executed on a different thread.

In general, blocks act just like a regular function. They run on the thread that called them (unless the block itself does something to call another thread etc...)